# gatsby ecommerce startkit + graphQL query issue

Tags: javascript, graphql, stripe-payments, gatsby

I come from a background of React, Mongo, node, a bit of SQL and Shopify (ton's of JS under my belt).

I came across this JAM stack idea and it seemed interesting and decided to try it out. I run into this problem that frankly I can't seem to wrap my head around after all the GraphQL tut's I've watched and articles I read, I'm clearly missing something important.

Traditionally in REST backend, you develop a scheme and your endpoints and then you ask them for the data.

Following [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/ecommerce-tutorial/) introduction, I get to the part where I query GraphQL, but I can't understand what or how I'm querying without developing a scheme. Use this code (after setting up Strip with test product / key)

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from "gatsby"

export default props => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SkusForProduct {
        skus: allStripeSku {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              currency
              price
              attributes {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={({ skus }) => (
      <div>
        {skus.edges.map(({ node: sku }) => (
          <p key={sku.id}>{sku.attributes.name}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  />
)
```

It states:

> You can validate your query and see what data is being returned in GraphiQL, which is available at http://localhost:8000/___graphql when running npm run develop.

Upon visiting this area, I noticed Query setup's and options. Is this where I develop the query that I'm using (or the schema?)

Slightly lost as what this sort of 'connection' looks like.

After following the full tutorial and replacing API keys, I get this error:

```
GraphQL Error Encountered 1 error(s):
- Unknown field 'allStripeSku' on type 'Query'.

      file: /Users/robert/Software/bDev/evu/src/components/products/skus.js
```

My gatsby-config:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})


module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },

  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-stripe`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-stripe`,
      options: {
        objects: ["Sku"],
        secretKey: process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
        downloadFiles: true,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],

}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, the graphiQL client is a convenient place to write test queries against gatsby's generated graphql schema. Usually it's difficult to know the shape of your data, since this process is abstracted away from users. GraphiQL provides code suggestion, type name, etc.. and once you got what you need, you can copy it over to your actual query in the source files.

You can also modify Gatsby's generated schema in `gatsby-node.js`, with this [api](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createResolvers).

Comment: What is blocking you though, did you run into an error?

Comment: @DerekNguyen ah thank you for the clarification, I actually get this error that I just added to my question. After I've followed the tutorial and replaced all the API keys and such.

Comment: ah I see, that means the plugin that handles fetching data from Stripe is not running. You have a `gatsby-source-stripe` entry in your `gatsby-config` right? Make sure there's a `Sku` in the `object` field, or maybe somehow it doesn't see the API keys, or your stripe account doesn't have any SKU set up yet?

Comment: I double check everything- source-stripe is there, there's a Sku in the object field as well. And stripe has Sku's. I'll add some more information to make sure I got it all setup right

Comment: oh, it looks like the API is loaded via different environment. Could it be that you added API keys to `.env.production` instead of `.env.development`?

Comment: to be frank- I copied the exact way to load the `.env.development` on how the showed it in the tutorial. I don't have a `.env.production` set up from what I can see

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out as I ran into the same head-scratching issue.

You have to create test products in stripe, not just live products. Make sure you've toggled the Viewing test data toggle in the Stripe admin. Then create your products.

You might need to clear your cache and public folders if it still isn't working.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to add `STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` to .env.development and not just `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` on its own (which is what the tutorial explicitly says to do). As soon as I'd added both, the build errors went away and the site could load up as normal; I also saw 'allStripePrice' appear as a field in GraphiQL. So the config should take this form:

```
# Stripe secret API key
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_xyz
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_xyz
```

I've raised this as a documentation [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/28385) in the GitHub repo and made Pull Request that addresses it. Feel free to upvote that issue.